# Is the tooth fairy depicted in Hellboy the first depiction of an evil tooth fairy?

Tags: hellboy

The tooth fairy creatures in Hellboy were creepy, verging on horrific, yet they seemed to be portrayed in the film as the skewed reality of a human myth. **Is this the first time that a tooth fairy has been portrayed as something evil-ish?**

Wikipedia says that, "unlike the well-established imagining of Santa Claus, differences in renderings of the tooth fairy are not as upsetting to children."

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_Be_Afraid_of_the_Dark_(2011_film\) This post-dates Hellboy 2 however. I am not aware of any other depictions of them as evil or scary.

Comment: It's from 2008, so postdates Hellboy, but I just had to mention The Tooth Fairy by Graham Joyce. That's one scary Tooth Fairy!

Comment: Well, there's [South Park's Tooth Fairy Tats 2000](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Tooth_Fairy_Tats_2000). But that's a different meaning of evil...

Comment: The Tooth Fairy was the first Bogeyman in the Discworld mythos.

Comment: That's described in Hogfather, 1996:  http://wiki.lspace.org/wiki/Book:Hogfather

Comment: @A.D, but it took the teeth to protect children against magic control (by safeguarding body parts that else might be used in spells), so arguably by the time it became the tooth fairy it was no longer evil.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the tooth fairy has been depicted as evil before.

I can't remember if they were in Hellboy 1 or 2.

Hellboy 2 was released 2008 and Hellboy 2004 (for example) and there is [Darkness Falls](http://uk.imdb.com/title/tt0282209/) (2003).

Also there is [The Tooth Fairy](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0473553/) (2006) if they were just in Hellboy 2.

Comment: The Tooth Fairies were in Hellboy 2, but I have no idea if they were based on creatures from the comics (which would push their date further back).

Comment: So it looks like a pretty recent idea that has been making the rounds in Hollywood.

Comment: Perhaps the inspiration to turn him/her evil came from Terry Pratchett's Discworld as mentioned in comments by @A.D & WayfaringStranger.

Answer (score 5):

In 1994 [Lawrence Schimel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lawrence_Schimel) published a story in the anthology [Young blood](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?55791) called "An eye for an eye, a tooth for a tooth".

The story is about a man who wakes up with one of his eyes missing and the tooth-fairy sitting by the foot of his bed. The tooth-fairy introduces his brother, who collects eyes, and explains that since  no one leaves eyes under their pillow the brother is very jealous and takes his revenge by collecting the organs fresh. The tooth fairy sits and watches while his brother takes the mans remaining eye and leaves a dollar coin for each eye. Before they leave the tooth-fairy says that their other brother is coming too. He collects hearts...

The tooth-fairy in this story does not do any evil acts himself, but he allows his brothers to maim and kill innocent people while he watches, which I would say is more than enough to label him as evil.

Answer (score -2):

You could consider the Tooth Fariy in [The Perry Bible Fellowship comic strip 187: Way Too Much](http://pbfcomics.com/187/) evil, or just incompetent.